# css animation with angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-animations

I seem to have a problem with an animation combined with angular.
I have the following div in my html:

```
<div class="show-hide" ng-show="questionOfType === '1'">...</div>
```

and I have the following css:

```
.show-hide {
        -webkit-transition:all linear 2s;
        transition:all linear 2s;
    }
```

so what I expected is once questionOfType will be set to 1 I will see the divs content appear with an animation, but It just appears regulary with no animation.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should load `$animate` as a module :

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

This is the example from their main page using css (and `$animate`)

```
<div ng-init="checked=true">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;"> Is Visible...
  </label>
  <div class="check-element sample-show-hide" ng-show="checked" style="clear:both;">
    Visible...
   </div>
</div>
```

$animate works in conjunction with your css

again an example from angular docs :

```
.sample-show-hide {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
   background:white;
}

.sample-show-hide {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
   transition:all linear 0.5s;
 }

.sample-show-hide.ng-hide {
   opacity:0;
 }
```

So change to :

```
<div class="check-element show-hide" ng-show="questionOfType === '1'">....</div>
```

and have you a model to use to no whether to show or hide?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CSS transitions cannot animate between `display: block` and `display: hidden`, which is what `ng-show` is toggling.

Instead, you could animate the opacity between 0 and 1:

```
.show-hide {
    -webkit-transition: opacity linear 2s;
    transition: opacity linear 2s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.show-hide.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And in the markup, toggle the `active` class I specified above using `ng-class`:

```
<div class="show-hide" ng-class="{'active': questionOfType === '1'}" ng-show="questionOfType === '1'">...</div>
```